# How to Split Dataset and plot in R

Tags: r, plot, split, lattice

I am using a data set like:

```
1  48434  14566
1  56711  6289
1  58826  4174
2  56626  6374
2  58888  4112
2  59549  3451
2  60020  2980
2  60468  2532
3  56586  6414
3  58691  4309
3  59360  3640
3  59941  3059
.
.
.
10  56757  6243
10  58895  4105
10  59565  3435
10  60120  2880
10  60634  2366
```

I need a plot in R of 3rd column for each value of first column i.e. for above data there would be 10 different plots of (each group 1-10) of values of 3rd column. x-axis is number of Iterations and Y-axis is the values with max 63000. I also need to connect the dots with a line in color red.
I am new to R and have been reading documentation but that confused me more. could any body plz help.

**EDIT: I actually want line graph of V3 values. the number of rows of v3 column would be on x-axis and v3 values on y-axis. And I want different graphs each for a group indicated by v1. Chase's solution works except that I want the axis shifted, the V3 values should be on y-axis.here is example**
[image]

**EDIT2: @Roman, Here is the code I am executing.**

```
library(lattice)
d <- read.delim("c:\\proj58\\positions23.txt",sep="")
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d$V1), function(x) {
    x$iterations <- order(x$V3, decreasing=TRUE)
    x
}))
xyplot(V3 ~ iterations | V1, type="l", data=d)
```

**This is the error I get,**

```
    > 
>  source("C:\\proj58\\plots2.R")
> d
       V1    V2    V3 iterations
1.1     1 48434 14566          1
1.2     1 56711  6289          2
1.3     1 58826  4174          3
1.4     1 59528  3472          4
```

**I am not getting any plot?? what am I missing**
OK: Got It. don't know what was wrong. Here it is,

[image]

2 more things, how to change V1 labels on the boxes to actual numbers like 1,2,...
secondly I have files that contain 100 groups, I tried one and it made all graphs on a single page (unreadable obviously), can I make these on more than one windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first you need to create a variable with the row number, for each subset of the first variable separately.  Here's one way to do it, by splitting the data set by the first variable, making a new variable that has the row number, and recombining.

You also probably want V1 to be a factor (a categorical variable).

```
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(d, d$V1), function(x) {
    x$iterations <- 1:nrow(x)
    x
}))
d$V1 <- factor(d$V1)
```

Then using the `lattice` library, you'd do something like

```
xyplot(V3 ~ iterations | V1, type="l", data=d)
```

To make the plots appear on more than one page, limit the number of plots on a page using the `layout` option.  You'll need to save the plot to a file that supports multi-page output to do that.  For example, for 5 rows and 5 columns:

```
trellis.device("pdf", file="myplot.pdf")
p <- xyplot(V3 ~ iterations | V1, type="l", data=d, layout=c(5,5))
plot(p)
dev.off()
```

Also, to make the plot appear when running the code using `source`, you need to specifically plot the output from the xyplot command, like

```
p <- xyplot(...)
plot(p)
```

When running at the console, this is not necessary as the `plot` (well, actually, the `print` function) is called on it by default.

Comment: Hehe, we got almost the same thing in mind. You may be closer, though (using V2 on the right side of the ~).

Comment: There is trouble, my data column V3 in other files is not always in decreasing order.It goes up and down.The function to create iterations above results in wrong graphs.

Comment: I've changed the code to use just the row number.  However, relying on your data set always staying in the same order is usually not a good idea. When you create the data set, consider storing the number of iterations as well as the other variables you have in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like charm. I have plotted with mix of your code and ggplot2. Wasn't expecting to finish this fast :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Chase said, please clarify on your question so that we can envision better what you're trying to achieve. To add to the heap of confusion, here's a `lattice` ballpark solution of what I think you may be after.

```
library(lattice)
fdt <- data.frame(col1 = seq(from = 1, to = 10, each = 10),
        col2 = round(56 * rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd = 5)),
        col3 = round(20 * rnorm(100, mean = 11,)))
xyplot(col3 ~ 1:100 | col1, data = fdt)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly following what it is that you want to plot, but here's an approach that should get your down the right path and you can fill in the appropriate plotting command...or clarify your question and explain what the final result of your plot should look like in more detail.

We are going to take advantage of two packages: `plyr` and `ggplot2`. We will use `plyr` to split up your data into the appropriate groups and then use `ggplot2` for the actual plotting. We'll take advantage of the `pdf()` function and put a different plot on each page.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(psych)    #For copying in data, not needed beyond that.

df <- read.clipboard(header = F)

pdf("test.pdf")
    d_ply(df, "V1", function(x)     #Split on the first column
        print(qplot(x$V3))          #Your plotting command should go here. This plots histograms.
    )
dev.off()                           #Close the plotting device.
```

This will generate an *n* page PDF where *n* represents the number of groups in V1 (your splitting column). If you'd rather have JPEG outputs, look at ?jpeg or the other graphics options for making other outputs.

**EDIT: As you can see, people interpreted your question in a few ways. If @Roman's solution is more what you want, here's roughly the same ggplot code**

```
qplot(col2, col3, data = fdt, geom = "point") + facet_wrap(~ col1 , nrow = 2)
```

Comment: This works, but it plots v3 values on x axis and count on y-axis. I want it other way round. plus I need a line graph instead of bar graph. thanx.

Comment: I have millions of lines of data, clipboard cannot take that much, how can I read directly from the file?

Comment: @user - @Roman's link is a great place to start. I'd take a step back (or two) and spend some time getting familiar with the R environment. What you are trying to do is a relatively simple task, but does combine several key fundamental aspects of working with the R environment. `read.table("myFileHere")` is probably what you are after. As for the plot, does V2 play into the plot at all? What order are we to assume for connecting the data points?

Comment: Thanx I read the doc above. I can get the file data now. V2 is useless data for my purposes. we just connect V3 points