# Is it possible to split data set into smaller pieces and plot on single graph (using R)?

Tags: r

I have a data set like below;

```
Row1: 000, 410000,32900,110
Row2: 100, 410100,32940,108
Row3: 200, 410190,33010,109
....
Row28: 2700, 414500,32090,110
```

is it possible to split this into 3 sets, 0-1000,  1000 to 2000, 2000 to 2700 and the plot all 3 on the same graph (only the first and fourth columns)?

I'm a self-learner and not very experienced. Closest I could get to achieving above was finding below discussion...but couldn't figure out how to tweak to do what I'm trying to achieve.

[How to Split Dataset and plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751651/how-to-split-dataset-and-plot-in-r)

Comment: Is column 1 a factor/categorical variable?

Comment: Hi Rui, Column one is actually kilometre of a road. 000m is beginning, then 100m, 200m... columns 2/3 are coordinates and 4th is the level. I'm trying to plot the kilometer (x) against the level for 1000m sections and show all on the same graph. Could do it in excel but there will be a lot more of these to sort :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of splitting the data set. It uses a standard `cumsum` trick to create a variable, `s`, defining the groups.

Then I plot the graphs in two different ways.

```
library(ggplot2)

s <- rep(c(1, rep(0, 9)), 3, length.out = nrow(df1))
s <- factor(cumsum(s))

ggplot(cbind(df1, s), aes(x = col1, y = col4, colour = s, group = s)) +
  geom_line()

ggplot(cbind(df1, s), aes(x = col1, y = col4, colour = s)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ s, scales = "free_x")
```

**Data creation code.**

```
set.seed(1234)
col1 <- seq(100, 2700, by = 100)
col4 <- sample(100:130, length(col1), TRUE)
col2 <- col3 <- seq_along(col1)
df1 <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```